# how to implement the equation counters of box in box

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikzmark, empheq

I'm trying to make a box in box with equation counters in the outside. The first image could be obtained by my code as follows,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array,cases}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


\begin{document}
    
This is what I get as follows:
\begin{empheq}[left=(M)\qquad, innerbox=\widefbox]{align}
    &\text{The equations are given as follows:} \notag\\
    &\qquad M=A+B \\
    &\qquad c=a+b \\
    &\qquad d=b+c \\
    &\text{where}  \notag\\
    &\qquad A=C+D \\
    & \qquad a=f+g \\
    & \qquad b=e+f
\end{empheq}

By tikzmark, the result what I obtain is not my desired one in the following.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw ([yshift=-3mm,xshift=3cm]{pic cs:start}) rectangle ([yshift=1mm,xshift=-2cm]{pic cs:end});
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzmark{start}
\begin{align}
    &\text{Equations are as follows:} \notag\\
    &\qquad M=A+B
\end{align}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
        c=a+b \\
        d=b+c
    \end{empheq}
\begin{align}
    &\text{where}  \notag\\
     &A=C+D
\end{align}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
     a=f+g \\
     b=e+f
\end{empheq}
\hfill
\tikzmark{end}
    
\end{document}
```

My desired result is as follows
[image: My desired result]

Could you please help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Please post your code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: I can't help with `tikz`, but within the `align`, the alignment point should be indicated by `&`; if you look closely, the equal signs don't exactly line up, and they should.  Enter them as `&=` to get the right spacing.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In your try, you didn't really make use of the `tikzmark` library.

Now, in a real example, you should pay attention and set the second mark (`SEn` in my example) on the longest equation, and then adapt the correction coordinate accordingly.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array,cases}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{empheq}[left=(M)\qquad, innerbox=\widefbox]{align}
  &\text{The equations are given as follows:} \notag\\
  &\qquad M=A+B \\
  &\qquad \tikzmark{NW1} c=a+b \\
  &\qquad d=b+c \tikzmark{SE1}\\
  &\text{where}  \notag\\
  &\qquad A=C+D \\
  & \qquad \tikzmark{NW2} a=f+g \\
  & \qquad b=e+f \tikzmark{SE2}
\end{empheq}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \draw[overlay] ($(pic cs:NW1)+(-1ex, 2.5ex)$)
  rectangle ($(pic cs:SE1)+(1ex, -1ex)$);
  \draw[overlay] ($(pic cs:NW2)+(-1ex, 2.5ex)$)
    rectangle ($(pic cs:SE2)+(1ex, -1ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Jerry Feng !  Is the answer of any use for you?

Comment: Thanks for @Barbara Beeton to give a nice answer of my question. I really appreciate your detailed explanations regarding tikzmark, which is useful to my writing of book and lecture notes.